# Implementing compareFilter of hbase in java

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

I want to do something like this in java like what we do in comparefilter in hbase

```
hbase(main):003:0> import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.CompareFilter
hbase(main):005:0> import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.SubstringComparator
hbase(main):006:0> scan 'CUTOFF21', {FILTER => org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.RowFilter.new(CompareFilter::CompareOp.valueOf('EQUAL'),SubstringComparator.new("C11\x09143662"))}
```

Answer (score 0):

See the below examples of `BinaryComparator`,`RegexStringComparator`, `SubstringComparator` from [here](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/hbase-the-definitive/9781491905845/ch04.html)

```
  Scan scan = new Scan();
    scan.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("colfam1"), Bytes.toBytes("col-1"));

    Filter filter1 = new RowFilter(CompareFilter.CompareOp.LESS_OR_EQUAL, 1
      new BinaryComparator(Bytes.toBytes("row-22")));
    scan.setFilter(filter1);
    ResultScanner scanner1 = table.getScanner(scan);
    for (Result res : scanner1) {
      System.out.println(res);
    }
    scanner1.close();

    Filter filter2 = new RowFilter(CompareFilter.CompareOp.EQUAL, 2
      new RegexStringComparator(".*-.5"));
    scan.setFilter(filter2);
    ResultScanner scanner2 = table.getScanner(scan);
    for (Result res : scanner2) {
      System.out.println(res);
    }
    scanner2.close();

    Filter filter3 = new RowFilter(CompareFilter.CompareOp.EQUAL, 3
      new SubstringComparator("-5"));
    scan.setFilter(filter3);
    ResultScanner scanner3 = table.getScanner(scan);
    for (Result res : scanner3) {
      System.out.println(res);
    }
    scanner3.close();
```

your case it will be something like this

```
 Filter filter3 = new RowFilter(CompareFilter.CompareOp.EQUAL, 3
          new SubstringComparator("C11\x09143662"));
        scan.setFilter(filter3);
        ResultScanner scanner3 = table.getScanner(scan);
        for (Result res : scanner3) {
          System.out.println(res);
        }
        scanner3.close();
```

Comment: was it useful ?